# How to do this dynamic where clause in EF

Tags: sql, entity-framework

Looking for some advice on how to tackle the following select query with EF.

*Note, I just need help with the SELECT via EF the create table/insert stuff is in there just for a sample of my table structure

```
  CREATE TABLE SampleTable(Foo INT, Bar VARCHAR(50))

INSERT SampleTable VALUES 
    (1,'GoodData'),
    (2, 'BetterData'),
    (2, 'Whatever'),
    (10, 'GoodData')


SELECT
    *
FROM
    SampleTable st
WHERE
    (Foo = 2 AND Bar = 'BetterData')
    OR (Foo = 1 AND Bar = 'GoodData') --There could be a 1000 of these line 'OR' lines


DROP TABLE SampleTable
```

Comment: Where do your conditions come from?  Are they in a dictionary or some other structure (or better yet in a table)?

Comment: They're not in another table, if they were I could join them in. I have them in an array of objects, that originated from a user request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of extension methods to help:

```
 public static class PredicateBuilder
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T>() { return f => true; }
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> False<T>() { return f => false; }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                                        Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
              (Expression.OrElse(expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                                         Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
              (Expression.AndAlso(expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
    }
}
```

Then to use it for your dynamic query needs:

```
 Expression<Func<SampleTableObject, bool>> predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<SampleTableObject>(); 
 foreach(var item in conditionsList)
 {
     predicate = predicate.Or(x=>x.Foo == item.Foo && x.Bar == item.Bar);
 }

 var data = EFContext.SampleTableObjects.Where(predicate);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another namespace in LINQ named **system.linq.dynamic**

It is very usefull if you want to make your query dynamicly via your code runtime.

Have a look on it!!

Answer (score 0):

```
.Where(sampleTable => sampleTable.Foo == 2 && sampleTable.Bar == "BetterData") ||
    sampleTable.Foo == 1 && sampleTable.Bar == "GoodData").ToList();
```

Comment: but I have an unknown number of conditions, maybe the better question is, how do I dynamically build the lambda?